# VS Code on Windows10 + CMake extension on WSL application

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to set up my development environment to build and debug WSL application on Windows 10.

The debug part I already managed to set it to work: [Windows 10's Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Debugger/gdb/Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux.md)

Now the only thing I need is to integrate the CMake functionality avoiding to build manually on the bash console.

Is this possible, can we call the cmake from VS Code on a WSL application from CMake extension or using any other option (example tasks... I never use it but reading about it, it seems that it can do the work i need no?)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a VS Code Task for that? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: Hi Mareks, yes vs code tasks works and I think I can do everything with that... but we should take advantage of great extensions that code has like CMake extension and with this extension I don't know how to set up everything...
I think if no one came with a good solution for the CMake extension for example i will post the tasks solution as the correct solution yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to help others a possible solution is described here: [VS Code on Windows10 + WSL application (compile and debug)](https://github.com/nesc1/win_code_wsl_test)

Tasks were used to solve the build issue... a better solution will be to use the CMake extension... but for now this is enough.

Thanks